# How to plot a stacked area chart for different groups across time

Tags: python, indexing, stacked-chart

My data is organized by miner and date and how many blocks each miner has mined per day. I want to use a stacked chart to plot daily mining output across time and miners.

```
miner date                     daily_block_reward
0x3 2015-07-30 00:00:00+00:00    1
0x3 2015-07-31 00:00:00+00:00    5
0x3 2015-08-30 00:00:00+00:00    3
0x5 2015-07-27 00:00:00+00:00    8
0x5 2015-07-29 00:00:00+00:00    11
0x5 2015-08-27 00:00:00+00:00    15
0x2 2015-08-01 00:00:00+00:00    4
0x2 2015-08-02 00:00:00+00:00    10
0x2 2015-08-27 00:00:00+00:00    11
```

[image: chart i want]

Comment: Assuming pandas, `reset_index`?

Comment: yes :) i edited the question